# вывод с базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

столкнулся с проблемой есть таблица с жанрами где id сериала - `tid`, и id жанра - `tid`
так-же на сайте есть select multiple это поиск по жанрам проблема в том что если `mysqli_query` задавать `WHERE jid IN (1,2,3,4,5)` то будет выводиться все сериалы где есть хотя-бы один из этих жанров, а нужно на оборот, где есть сразу все эти жанры, надеюсь поможете)

вот код обработчика PHP -

```
        $sjanrs = $_POST['janrs'];//Выбранные жанры

        array_walk($sjanrs, function (&$janr) {
        $janr = (int)$janr;
        });  
        unset($janr);

        $sjanrse = implode(',', $sjanrs);//вставляем запятые

        $Result = mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "SELECT `tid` FROM `janrs` WHERE `jid` IN ($sjanrse)");

        while ($Glob = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {// И т.д
```

А вот поиск select multiple -

```
<select name="sjanrs[]" id="janrs" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="По каким жанрам искать">
                                <option                             value="1">
                    Альтернативная история
                </option>
                                <option                             value="2">
                    Альтернативная реальность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="3">
                    Ангелы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="4">
                    Андроиды
                </option>
                                <option                             value="5">
                    Антивойна
                </option>

</select>
```

- заметил что сериалы где есть из выбранных жанров есть более 1 жанра совпадающего с жанрами сериала то сериал повторяется столько раз сколько из выбранных жанров есть в сериале

Comment: Опишу принципиальную логику. Делаете `GROUP BY id_фильма` проверяете, чтобы `COUNT(*)` был равен количеству элементов в `IN (.....)`

Comment: select distinct